# Uptime checks keeping some AppEngine instances alive and others not?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

We've noticed that using GCP's Monitoring Uptime checks on one AppEngine service appears to keep it 'alive' unnecessarily - removing the monitoring configuration reduced the running instances to 0. However, we have two other AppEngine services that would happily reduce to 0 instances, even with the monitoring in place.

We've been unable to find any difference in configuration. The one other visible difference we spotted was in the 'Traffic' graphs, the instances that still shut down included 'Sent (cached)' and 'Received (cached)' as series on the graph (along side Sent and Received):

[image]

Whereas the 'problem' service only has Sent and Received:

[image]

There is no cloud load balancing in place - we're just using AppEngine to map the endpoints.

Config for both look like this, with different handlers configured:

```
runtime: python310
env: standard
instance_class: F1
handlers:
  - *snip*
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: automatic
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: automatic
  max_pending_latency: automatic
service_account: XXXX@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
```

Can anyone clarify what might be different between these? Thank you.

Comment: Seems like your issue needs internal logs and more in-depth analysis  to check the route cause. feel free to contact [google support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub)

Comment: Thanks @SathiAiswarya - having to ask here as we’re a non-profit and have no paid support plan. From my understanding this means we can only raise billing issues. Is there any other way to raise this issue?